# VB6 calling WCF: Could not find endpoint element

Tags: c#, wcf, vb6, interop

I have a legacy VB6 app that needs to call .Net .dll in order to invoke a WCF web service.

At first, I got this annoying message:

> Could not find endpoint element with name 'DocumentMetadataPortSOAP12'
> and contract 'CODSRef.DocumentMetadataType' in the ServiceModel client
> configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
> found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
> this name could be found in the client element.

I followed this link - [Using app.config with Interop Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175983/using-app-config-with-interop-controls) - and it helped me get my VB6 test exe working:

1. Copied an app.config from a net test client
2. Renamed it `MyVb6Test.exe.config` (the same name as the VB6 exe).

So far, so good.

CURRENT PROBLEM:

The actual client is a VB6.exe that calls a VB6 .dll, which calls the .Net/COM-aware .dll:

```
  MyLegacyVb6App.exe
    +-> MyNewVB6plugin.dll
          +-> MyNewdotNet.dll
                +-> WCF
```

Even though I created `MyLegacyVb6App.exe.config` - exactly like the working VB6 test - I'm still getting "Could not find endpoint element with name 'DocumentMetadataPortSOAP12'..."

Here's the .Net code in "MyNewDotNet.dll":

```
DocNotificationRequesttype wsRequest = new DocNotificationRequesttype();
DocumentMetadataTypeClient wsClient =  new DocumentMetadataTypeClient("DocumentMetadataPortSOAP12",  m_wsUrl);
DocNotificationResponsetype wsResponse = wsClient.DocNotification(wsRequest);
```

Is there any reason I actually need an "app.config"?  Is there any way I can "hard code" whatever it needs directly in my C# code?

What other alternatives do I have for my scenario: `VB6 exe -> VB6 .dll -> .Net/Interop .dll => WCF`?

Comment: I suspect your .NET DLL cannot read the configuration file. you need to make a code change to the .NET DLL source code so that it can read its own configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by using an App.config after all.

PROBLEM:

Because my .Net .dll was being invoked from a VB6/COM .dll called from a VB6 .exe (with gosh knows how many VB6/COM components in the middle) ... .Net happened to be looking for the app.config in an *UNEXPECTED* place - *NOT* in thw same directory as the VB6 .exe itself (?!?)

SOLUTION:

I used [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.configurationfile(v=vs.110).aspx) tp get the actual location where .Net was looking for app.config:

```
LogMsg(">>AppConfigFile=" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
```