# Cannot execute SSIS package from vb6

Tags: ssis, vb6

I am trying to execute a simple SSIS package from vb6 application.
I can execute the same package from c#.

This is my code in vb6:

```
  pkgLocation = "c:\Package.dtsx"
  Set dtsApp = New Application


  Set package = dtsApp.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, True, Nothing)
  Set pkgContainer = package

  pkgResults = package.Execute

  If (pkgResults = 0) Then
   MsgBox "Success"
  Else
    MsgBox "Fail"
  End If
```

In my log file, I see this error:
The Execute method on the task returned error code 0x80131621 (Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.). The Execute method must succeed, and indicate the result using an "out" parameter.

I my c# program I have to add an App.config file to resolve the same error:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

But How can I do the same from vb6 application?

Edit 1:

In my vb6 project I am using this references:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\DTS.DLL  - Microsoft DTS Runtime 1.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\MsDtsSrvrUtil.dll - Dts Server 9.0 Type Library

The SSIS package was made with : Sql Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in this post [Using app.config with Interop Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175983/using-app-config-with-interop-controls)

In short : If my VB6 exe es called VB6.exe , I  need to put in the same directory as the file VB6.exe the App.config file but renamed VB6.exe.config

Comment: As below, thought it might be an app path error. All working fine now?

Answer (score 0):

Your version of calling the object is older/newer than the version you are trying to open it seems.

You need to reference the correct version object in your app under project/references.

Comment: Hello Andre, I edit the post to show what are the references I am using. I do not know what are the correct references. The SSIS package was made with Sql Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Have a look at this link, a bit outdated, just change to .Net 4.0 when doing the reference. Sure this will solve...   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719110(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I was trying with the link you gave me, and still not work

Comment: Mmmm, will have to play around with this... Is it possible to add the file Package.dtsx to your application folder and then call the App.Path method to override possible privilege issues -  Set package = dtsApp.LoadPackage(App.Path, True, Nothing). Don't think it is the issue here, will revert back soon.

Comment: Hi Andre. See the answer I proposed.  Thanks for your time